# how to get existing AWS arn certificate in order to use it in serverlessframework

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless-framework

is there a way , to get existing AWS certificate ARN , when i am in my serverless framework deployment file , i need a way to get the arn of the certificate when i know only the name of the certificate

Answer (score 1):

You can usually infer the the entire structure of ARN's inside AWS. For example this is the ARN of a DynamoDB table in my AWS account (the X's are my account ID):

> arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:XXXXXXXXXXX:table/awesome-mytable-dev

These ARN's are the same structure every time:

> arn:aws:[service name]:[region name or blank]:[accountID]:[entity
> within the service]/[name of entity]

Try manually creating a certificate, then seeing how the ARN is structured, then just "build" the ARN you need to match the same structure. Recent versions of the Serverless Framework even allow you to add in your AWS information as variables using ${aws:region} or ${aws:accountId}.

Comment: thanks , i agree with the region and account number , but the last part is the certificate Identifier , and in my case its look like a GUID